# How to add new user level in Orangehrm and add some credentials?

Tags: orangehrm

I am trying to create a new level of user which is like an admin but has less credentials. He cant configure settings of the modules but can view, add, edit, delete data of the employees. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is hidden "User Roles" module in OrangeHRM, it provides you all the permissions required to change/assign particular menu items to various roles. This needs some custom work such as updating the values on check/uncheck but should be a simple job to do. And tables names are shared by @patxrick should help you to do the modification easily.

Comment: How to access this hidden module? Is that a part of free version? I am using v4.7

Answer (score -1):

You need to insert new user role in `ohrm_user_role` table.
Then add related records in tables like `ohrm_user_role_screen` table and `ohrm_user_role_data_group`.